# Git error when connecting to server through ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I'm on Windows 7 and I want to connect to server through ssh. But I got an error after authentication (which was succesfully).

```
fatal: Interactive git shell is not enabled.
hint: ~/git-shell-commands should exist and have read and execute access.
```

I have a git but I googled that is because of lack git-shell-commands directory. And yes, I didn't have this folder in my home directory after git installation, but I created it and gave a permission. I also installed something like 'msysgit' (cause when I installed a git from exe I didn't have git-shell-commands directory, in msysgit there was this folder so I copied it to my home directory) but still have a problem and got this error. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What command do you use "to connect to server through ssh"? What software (OS and Git or some Git front-end) the server runs?

Comment: I'm using command: 'ssh login@host' and I provide a password. I got connection but immediately I got this error and 'connection is closed'. Server is on linux but not sure on what specific system.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the proper login shell on the server side for your *git* users. Usually it is located at */usr/local/bin/git-shell*

Comment: Ok, but where it can be in windows? In bin folder in git installation directory I cannot find this file.

Comment: @caro2 That's a server-side issue. Is your git-server running on Windows as well as the client?

Comment: I didn't know that problem is on the server side. I don't have an access to server but it is for sure on linux. So, I have to contact with administrator of this server. Or is there different solution?

Comment: @caro2 Yes, you should contact the server administrator.

Answer (score 0):

**Apply these two commands it will resolve this issue:**

To enable git-shell for your_git_user:

`usermod -s /usr/bin/git-shell your_git_user`

To change owner of your_git_user directory recursively:

`chown -R your_git_user:your_users_group /home/your_git_user`

**You may add git shell commands using below command:**

`cp /usr/share/doc/git-1.8.3.1/contrib/git-shell-commands/ /home/your_git_user/git-shell-commands -R`